# Dynamic Pop-up Menu (Select box) in Dashcode

Tags: iphone, data-binding, popup, datasource, dashcode

I'm trying to use Dashcode to create a drop-down list for an iPhone Web app. I want the list to be set dynamically based on a data source, and for the selected item to be set by a separate data source.

I've figured-out how to set the parameters on the data source to get it to alter the contents, and have the data in valid JSON, but can't figure-out how to connect up the data source to make anything but a blank pop-up appear. I've tried connecting arrays and associative arrays to each of the bindings and still can't get anything (except an error when I try and connect it to the content)

So... Anyone out there done this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the code out of Dashcode library? There are a number of prewritten snippets in there and often with a bit more detail on the Dashcode docs on the apple site.

The other way is to download some widgets and then disassemble them to see how someone else has done it.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'll be sure to have a look at that. I was looking around for documentation and finding nothing. I was also looking for iPhone-specific examples when in retrospect if the same system is used across dashcode then I could have broadened my search. I'd vote your answer up, but it tells me I've not got enough reputation yet, sorry!